# libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing

Tags: software

After download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/reduce-algebra/files/ and unzip reduce-windows64-20101007.zip

failed to open reduce, got error in window 8
libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software that you're trying to download was compiled with the GCC compiler and requires a run time library that is provided with that compiler.  Installing the gcc compiler on your system will probably resolve the issue.

Comment: let me try it tonight. Thx.

Comment: How do gcc compiler installed in window 8?

Comment: There are two common software distributions for Windows that include gcc.  The most commonly used one is Cygwin.  Some folks use another package called Mingw.  It appears that this particular DLL might be part of the Mingw version of gcc, but I'm not sure of that.   I'd suggest reporting this problem to the folks who maintain reduce and asking them what environment they built the Windows version of reduce in.

Comment: it should be enough to add the missing DLL to the directory where binary is. It's from SJLJ flavor of GCC, probably from MinGW-w64 (MinGW from mingw.org is DW2 flavor). But as Brian wrote, first report it to developers.